# Update Checkboxlist to database in asp.net C#

Tags: asp.net

I want to update multi checkboxlist value to the the database. I already databound my checkboxlist from other table which is the medicine table. Now i want to update my value to consultation table, but i can not

`

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     try
    {
       for (int i = 0; i < txtcheckbox.Items.Count - 1; i++)
        {
          if (txtcheckbox.Items[i].Selected == true)
          {
                str = str + txtcheckbox.Items[i].Text + ",";
            }
         }


        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
        String sql = "UPDATE [consultation]  set mname3 = " + str + "  WHERE [conid] = @conid";

        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con);

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@conid", txtconid);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mname3", str);

        int j = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        if (j > 0)
        {
            Label2.Visible = true;
            Label2.Text = "Successfully Complete Dispensary";

            txtconid.Text = "";
        }
        else
        {
            Label2.Visible = true;
            Label2.Text = "Not Successfully Complete Dispensary";

            txtconid.Text = "";
        }
             con.Close();
       }
        catch 
        {
          Label2.Visible = true;
           Label2.Text = "Error";

            txtconid.Text = "";
        }
}







    `
```

Comment: What 's happening when u say "YOU CANNOT", are u getting a db error, string parsing issue, or not able to find the values???

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have exception here. Because:

> String sql = "UPDATE [consultation]  set mname3 = " + str + "  WHERE [conid] = @conid";

here you use concatenation of strings and your sql query will look like:
UPDATE [consultation]  set **mname3 = sometextvale**  WHERE [conid] = @conid

mname3 have nvarchar sql type I guess, so you need to put string value in qoutes:

> String sql = "UPDATE [consultation]  set mname3 = **'** " + str + " **'**  WHERE [conid] = @conid";

Or you can use paramaeter for sql query, like you already did for @conid:

> String sql = "UPDATE [consultation]  set mname3 = **@mname3** WHERE [conid] = @conid";

It's better solution in security way.

Some additional comments:

> for (int i = 0; i < txtcheckbox.Items.Count - 1; i++)

Are you sure here should be txtcheckbox.Items.Count - 1? You will lost the last one.

And the 2nd one: Mix code for construction and execution query (DAL) in code behind of page with some kind of business logic not a good practice =)